# How to set JFrame in fullscreen using users native resolution?

Tags: java, swing, render, game-development

I am trying to create a little game for a project in university. Since I need to update the screen permanently I am looking for a good render loop implementation. It should be full screen. I found this on [gamedev.net - Java Games: Active Rendering](https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/_/technical/general-programming/java-games-active-rendering-r2418/):

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleFullScreenGame {
        
  static boolean running;
        
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
            
// Create game window...
JFrame app = new JFrame();
app.setIgnoreRepaint( true );
app.setUndecorated( true );
            
// Add ESC listener to quit...
app.addKeyListener( new KeyAdapter() {
  public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
    if( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE )
        running = false;
      }
});
            
// Get graphics configuration...
GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();

// Change to full screen
gd.setFullScreenWindow( app );
if( gd.isDisplayChangeSupported() ) {
  gd.setDisplayMode( 
    new DisplayMode( 640, 480, 32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN )
  );
}
            
// Create BackBuffer...
app.createBufferStrategy( 2 );
BufferStrategy buffer = app.getBufferStrategy();
            
// Create off-screen drawing surface
BufferedImage bi = gc.createCompatibleImage( 640, 480 );

// Objects needed for rendering...
Graphics graphics = null;
Graphics2D g2d = null;
Color background = Color.BLACK;
Random rand = new Random();
            
// Variables for counting frames per seconds
int fps = 0;
int frames = 0;
long totalTime = 0;
long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long lastTime = curTime;
            
running = true;
while( running ) {
  try {
    // count Frames per second...
    lastTime = curTime;
    curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    totalTime += curTime - lastTime;
    if( totalTime > 1000 ) {
      totalTime -= 1000;
      fps = frames;
      frames = 0;
    } 
    ++frames;

    // clear back buffer...
    g2d = bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor( background );
    g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, 639, 479 );
                            
    // draw some rectangles...
    for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i ) {
      int r = rand.nextInt(256);
      int g = rand.nextInt(256);
      int b = rand.nextInt(256);
      g2d.setColor( new Color(r,g,b) );
      int x = rand.nextInt( 640/2 );
      int y = rand.nextInt( 480/2 );
      int w = rand.nextInt( 640/2 );
      int h = rand.nextInt( 480/2 );
      g2d.fillRect( x, y, w, h );
    }
                            
    // display frames per second...
    g2d.setFont( new Font( "Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12 ) );
    g2d.setColor( Color.GREEN );
    g2d.drawString( String.format( "FPS: %s", fps ), 20, 20 );
                            
    // Blit image and flip...
    graphics = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage( bi, 0, 0, null );
                            
    if( !buffer.contentsLost() )
      buffer.show();
                            
  } finally {
    // release resources
    if( graphics != null ) 
      graphics.dispose();
    if( g2d != null ) 
      g2d.dispose();
  }
}
            
gd.setFullScreenWindow( null );
System.exit(0);
}
}
```

I executed the code and there are two things I am wondering about:

My display resolution is 1920x1080. The code is using 640x480. Therefore the rendered rectangles look like a 640x480 picture upscaled to 1920x1080 meaning you have huge pixels and the code doesn't take avantage of the higher posible resolution of the display. How can I adapt the code to actually use the native display resolution of the user?

Second, usually what you see when you take a look on games code is a rendering loop living in its own thread to not block the main thread. However thats not the case here. Why? I assume because the JFrame already lives in its own thread created by swing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: *How can I adapt the code to actually use the native display resolution of the user?*  Most games have a limited set of resolutions and ask the user which resolution he wants to use.  Each resolution has either its own set of images or the game has one set of images at the highest resolution and downscales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of issues with this code.

First of all, when you are checking (polling) a flag variable in the main thread, that will be updated by a key listener, which will be called in the event dispatch thread, the minimum you have to do, is to declare that variable `volatile`.

Then, there is no point in using `JFrame` when you don’t use the Swing framework at all. Further, it’s nonsensical to request double buffering from the AWT and then, use a `BufferedImage` for another buffering atop the already buffered operation.

Using the native resolution is as easy as removing the `setDisplayMode(…)` call. After turning the window to full screen, you can simply use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on it to get the actual dimensions for the operations (it’s not needed for the buffered image, as that was obsolete anyway).

```java
public class SimpleFullScreenGame {
    static volatile boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create game window...
        Frame app = new Frame();
        app.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        app.setUndecorated(true);

        // Add ESC listener to quit...
        app.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) running = false;
            }
        });

        GraphicsDevice dev = app.getGraphicsConfiguration().getDevice();
        // Change to full screen
        dev.setFullScreenWindow(app);

        int width = app.getWidth(), height = app.getHeight();

        // Create BackBuffer...
        app.createBufferStrategy(2);
        BufferStrategy buffer = app.getBufferStrategy();

        // Objects needed for rendering...
        Color background = Color.BLACK, textColor = Color.GREEN;
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
        ThreadLocalRandom rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

        // Variables for counting frames per seconds
        int fps = 0, frames = 0, totalTime = 0;
        long currTime = System.nanoTime(), lastTime;

        while(running) {
            // count Frames per second...
            lastTime = currTime;
            currTime = System.nanoTime();
            totalTime += currTime - lastTime;
            if(totalTime > 1_000_000_000) {
                totalTime -= 1_000_000_000;
                fps = frames;
                frames = 0;
            }
            frames++;

            Graphics gfx = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
            gfx.setColor(background);
            gfx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            // draw some rectangles...
            for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
                gfx.setColor(new Color(rand.nextInt(0x1000000)));
                int x = rand.nextInt(width/2), y = rand.nextInt(height/2);
                int w = rand.nextInt(width/2), h = rand.nextInt(height/2);
                gfx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
            }

            // display frames per second...
            gfx.setFont(font);
            gfx.setColor(textColor);
            gfx.drawString("FPS: " + fps, 20, 20);

            gfx.dispose();
            if(!buffer.contentsLost()) buffer.show();
        }

        dev.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

<sup>I made some other small improvements.</sup>